# Are there any advantages to playing COD: Black Ops Multiplayer in 3D vs. 2D?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

Does anyone know if there is a big difference between the 2D and 3D versions of Call of Duty: Black Ops multiplayer?  I was just curious if there are any advantages to playing in 3D (players are much easier to notice, determining distance from targets is easier, etc.)  I've been playing all of the new COD games, but don't have a 3D tv and was wondering if it's any better.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I fear you only have disadvantages as from what I've read so far, CODs 3D isn't spectacular with regards to the crosshair positioning and such

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tried it once at a computer store. Play 2D at home otherwise.

Bullet flight mechanics are non-existent in this game, therefore the depth axis won't be of any use.

Distant targets seem even fuzzier on 3D. You can't spot campers in the distance. And let's be realistic: there are a lot of campers out there in multiplayer.
I must say I do pretty fine on judging the distance to make a grenade shot from afar. 2D is definitely the better way of doing this.

All in all it was an interesting experience for me, and I heard from the store owner, that some people felt dizzy 10 minutes into the game.

I would suggest you to try it out and see it for yourself. It's a highly subjective experience.

Comment: Looks like I'll just stick to 2D, but keep my eye open for a chance to try 3D.  Probably won't be improved until the next go-around.

Answer (score 0):

I just don't think the technology has matured enough to actually produce an advantage in-game. You end up with some after-affects on the screen to give it that 3D look that are limited in scope and in my opinion, make things harder to see.